# Accessing Sandboxes of Google APIs from PHP Client Library

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

Just wondering if there's any means to allow for the PHP Client Library's services to access their API's sandbox environment, instead of just their real ones. (I'm doing this for dfareporting, myself)

Comment: what sandbox environments?

Comment: Maybe I'm calling it the wrong thing? In the case of DFA, I can head over to sandbox.google.com/dfa (as opposed to google.com/dfa) and get a separate test environment.